# Can't mount squashfs loop during initramfs

Tags: mount, initramfs, loop-device, initrd, squashfs

I am trying to mount a squashfs file during initramfs.
I have included loop and squashfs modules.

Currently using `mount /foo.squashfs /mountpoint`
or `mount -t squashfs -o loop /foo.squashfs /mountpoint`
results with `Error: block device required.`

However, first setting up loop device manually with
`losetup /dev/loop0 /foo.squashfs`
then mounting with `mount /dev/loop0 /mountpoint` is sucessful.

I suspect I am missing a kernel module, but I am not sure.

Comment: Just go with the successful method. busybox can be weird sometimes. If in doubt, check lsmod before and after successful mount. Maybe strace it.

Comment: Currently I solved the problem by copying the 'mount' executable from the linux environment.

Answer (score 1):

The reason ended up being, that the environment, on which I was building the initramfs. did not have busybox installed. Update-initramfs defaulted to using klibc, which did not have many features, including automatic loop mounting.